# highcharts Annotations module addAnnotations bug

Tags: highcharts

I have encountered a weird bug. To reproduce it, I do this.

I have one chart that I reuse. I first load the chart with data_1, and also annotations_1 using addAnnotation(), which works.

Then I update the chart with data_2, and also delete annotations_1 via removeAnnotations(id). And load annotations_2, which works

If I now come back and reload data_1 , delete annotations_2, and try to reload annotations_1, it doesn't work. The chart data shows up fine but no annotations.

**[UPDATED]**
    I can't save or fork a jsfiddle !?, so I put my code here. Right now I have a slightly different error. The data is never re-updated if I click on 'button 1' a second time. After doing 'button 1', then 'button 2'.

html

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/annotations.js"></script>

<button id="btn1">1</button>
<button id="btn2">2</button>
<div id="container"></div>
```

css

```
#container, .highcharts-data-table table {
    min-width: 350px; 
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: 1em auto;
}

#container {
    height: 450px;
}
```

js + load jquery

```
// Data generated from http://www.bikeforums.net/professional-cycling-fans/1113087-2017-tour-de-france-gpx-tcx-files.html
var elevationData_1 = [   [70.6, 597],
    [70.7, 591],
    [70.8, 590],
    [70.9, 587],
    [71.0, 584],
    [71.1, 584],
    [71.2, 582],
    [71.3, 574],
    [71.4, 572],
    [71.5, 570],
    [71.6, 572],
    [71.7, 573],
    [71.8, 575],
    [71.9, 578],
    [72.0, 590],
    [72.1, 595],
    [72.2, 595],]
var elevationData_2 = [ [71.9, 578],
    [72.0, 590],
    [72.1, 595],
    [72.2, 595],
    [72.3, 579],
    [72.4, 581],
    [72.5, 583],
    [72.6, 583],
    [72.7, 583],
    [72.8, 583],
    [72.9, 580],
    [73.0, 579],
    [73.1, 584],
    [73.2, 587],
    [73.3, 594],
    [73.4, 597],
    [73.5, 597],
    [73.6, 596],]

// Now create the chart
var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {

    chart: {
        type: 'area',
        zoomType: 'x',
        panning: true,
        panKey: 'shift',
        scrollablePlotArea: {
            minWidth: 600
        }
    },



    xAxis: {
        labels: {
            format: '{value} km'
        },
        minRange: 5,
        title: {
            text: 'Distance'
        },

    },

    yAxis: {
        startOnTick: true,
        endOnTick: false,
        maxPadding: 0.35,
        title: {
            text: null
        },
        labels: {
            format: '{value} m'
        }
    },


    series: [{

        lineColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1],
        color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2],
        fillOpacity: 0.5,
        name: 'Elevation',
        id: 'Elevation',

        marker: {
            enabled: false
        },
        threshold: null
    }]

});

  $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#btn1").click(
            function () {
               chart.get('Elevation').setData(elevationData_1)
            }            
        );
         $("#btn2").click(
            function () {
               chart.get('Elevation').setData(elevationData_2)
            }            
        );
    });
```

Comment: Could you reproduce your code on some online editor which I could debug and see how it works?

Comment: question is updated with some code

Comment: Here is a demo with your code. Could you add annotations and describe the steps to see the issue? https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8xrm6hks/

Comment: It's working fine in the jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/dbyp5e47/1/ , can't reproduce it

Comment: I did some digging and it has to do with series.setData and my chart is highcharts-vue wrapper. The first time I use setData, it works fine. But if I use a copy of the dataset in setData again, it paints the chart fine but the data length is not set right....something is not right Would you have a suggestion try out ? –

Comment: on the second time, debugging shows my data array  has a length of 300, but the first 60 is undefined

Comment: Have you set the updatePoints flag to false as I did in the demo? I mean: chart.series[0].setData(data, true, false, false). API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#setData

Comment: yes -  "series[0].setData(obj['candles'],true,false,false)"

Comment: Hm, interesting. Are you able to reproduce this case in vue? Here is a basic template which you can use: https://codesandbox.io/s/nw750l07nj Without see it and debugging it's hard to say more.

Comment: Here is the codebox : https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-onb6p. After awhile, it stops working when clicking from one button to another

Comment: I made a non-vue highcharts on jsfiddle. No errors with setData and annotations.